# What is the difference between space and blank?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

I currently translated the German word Leerzeichen to English and got the term blank. But when I search (e.g whether there's a blank before a percent sign) everyone is writing about spaces. That's why I'm a bit confused now.

Comment: OR check out [this usage chart.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=space+between+two+words%2Cblank+between+two+words&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: Yes, thank you!